# ldap installation in ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu-10.04, openldap

during `LDAP` installation in ubuntu the following error has
been occured.

```
"ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)"
```

can any one help me to figure it out ???

Comment: Did you fall prey to [this problem](http://www.openldap.org/lists/openldap-software/200312/msg00336.html)?

Comment: wht do u mean by it ???

Comment: ldapsearch -xLLL -b cn=config -D cn=admin,cn=config -W olcDatabase=hdb olcAccess

Enter LDAP Password: 
ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the LDAP database, re-configure slapd and restart it. Then add the ldiffs again. It worked in my case when I tried it on 9.04.

```
rm -rf /var/backups/*.ldapdb
dpkg-reconfigure slapd
/etc/init.d/slapd restart
```

and then add your ldif file again to DB.

```
ldapadd -x -W -D "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com" -f ~/people.ldif
```

Comment: thnks Eshan                                                                          i got an answer from         http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057257/ubuntu-10-04-lucid-openldap-invalid-credentials-issue